# long due vs long overdue

Tags: meaning

This is just a quick question, is there a difference in meaning between “long due” and “long overdue”? And if yes, can anyone tell me the meaning?

I already know what “long overdue” means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "long overdue" is stronger than "long due" in the following sense: "long due" suggests that this something is beyond schedule, but in a way that is almost acceptable. "Long overdue", on the other hand, means that this something is so much beyond the deadline that all hopes have been lost, and your landlord will have to litigate, and you had better worry.

Also, "long overdue" seems to be more idiomatic; a Google search for ["long due"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long%20due%22) returned 1.1 mln results, and for ["long overdue"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long%20overdue%22), 15.4 mln results.